# SQL statement to select and store items into a shelf 2 items deep

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote some SQL code for a VB.net program that allowed for an item to be stored into a rack. Each rack spot had the capacity for one item and only one item could be inserted into it. My code selected the top empty rack and then filled it to be later checked out. Now the problem has changed so that you can put 2 items in each spot. I am not sure how to change my code so that I can allow for an extra item.

I have 2 tables

*Table 1*

```
RackID, RackName, Active

The RackID is a primary key and is just 1,2,3,4....etc.etc.

The RackName is a description of the location; H01, H02, H03....etc.etc.

The Active is a bit that allows me to make the rack active or inactive for item storage.
```

*Table 2* :is a log of all items checked in/out and who checked it in and out

```
columns: RackID, ItemNumber, NameIn, NameOut, TimeIn, TimeOut

RackID is the identifier between the 2 tables, is also 1,2,3,5....etc.etc.

ItemNumber is the distinct item, PLEASE NOTE IT IS A DATETIME

NameIn and NameOut are both int fields that tie into a name table

Time in/out are both time stamps
```

I need help with the code to do the stored procedure. It needs to be able to loop through all the rack slots and then pick one to insert an item into. The constraints are that no more than 2 items can be inserted into one rack location, the program needs to put 1 item into every rack before it begins inserting the second one. So every rack location needs at least one item in it before the second one is added. Here is the code i used to do the stored procedure for just one item.

```
INSERT INTO table2 (RackID, ItemNumber, TimeIn, NameIN) 
SELECT Top 1 RackID, 
             cast(@Date as smalldatetime), 
             cast (getdate() as smalldatetime), 
             Cast(@Name as int)
FROM table1 
WHERE RackID NOT IN 
       (SELECT table1.RackID 
        FROM table1 
        left join table2 on table2 = table1 
        WHERE Active = 1 
              AND TimeOut IS NULL 
              AND NOT TimeIn IS NULL) 
AND RackName LIKE 'H%' 
ORDER BY LocID ASC
```

Comment: First question....why is ItemNumber a datetime? That is one of the strangest things I have heard in quite some time.

Comment: @SeanLange It has to do with the way we label our products. its an internal process.

Comment: No offense but that is awful. You are being forced to put a primary key on a datetime datatype. I can see if you use the current time to generate an itemnumber but a datetime as the item number makes no sense to me at all. That however is way off topic here...

Comment: @SeanLange it has to do with when the item was decided to be produced. The item number is essentially when it was pushed to be built. The actual item number is a string of numbers that are pulled from the datetime to form an item number.

Comment: That's what I figured. I would suggest using either a varchar or a bigint instead of datetime. Otherwise you have to constantly cast this back and forth.

Comment: That would be nice. However, it is not my call there. Looking at writing this new sql statement, I think I need some type of if statement followed by a loop to select the total amount of items not checked out under each RackID and then write the code dependent on what the feedback is.

Comment: No you don't need a loop. I am working on something for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a tally for this. I keep a view on my systems named cteTally so I can just use it whenever I need it. Here is the code for that.

```
create View [dbo].[cteTally] as

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )
select N from cteTally
GO
```

Now to deal with your issue. I had to make some assumptions about some of the columns and such but this should at least get you close enough to tweak it into shape.

```
create table Rack
(
    RackID int identity primary key clustered
    , RackName varchar(25) not null
    , Active bit not null
    , NumSlots int not null 
)

create table RackItem
(
    ItemNumber datetime primary key clustered
    , RackID int not null foreign key references Rack(RackID)
    , NameIn int null
    , NameOut int null
    , TimeIn datetime null
    , TimeOut datetime null
)

insert Rack
select 'Rack1', 1, 2 union all
select 'Rack2', 1, 2 union all
select 'Rack3', 1, 2;

insert RackItem
select getdate(), 1, 1, 1, GETDATE(), null union all
select dateadd(second, 1, getdate()), 1, 1, 1, GETDATE(), null union all
select dateadd(second, 2, getdate()), 2, 1, 1, GETDATE(), null;

select *
from Rack r
join RackItem ri on ri.RackID = r.RackID;

with NumberedRackItems as
(
    select ri.*, ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by RackID order by ItemNumber) as RowNum
    from RackItem ri
)
select 
    r.RackID
    , r.RackName
    , MAX(case when t.N = 1 then ri.ItemNumber end) as ItemNumber1
    , MAX(case when t.N = 2 then ri.ItemNumber end) as ItemNumber2
from cteTally t
join Rack r on t.N <= r.NumSlots
left join NumberedRackItems ri on ri.RackID = r.RackID and ri.RowNum = t.N
where r.Active = 1
group by r.RackID
    , r.RackName
order by RackID;
```

Comment: wow...this is a bit out of my league. I am going to start trying to research all of this and get it figured out. A quick question when you create a table or a view, are those short term tables that you use for a quick query and then are gone?

Comment: No those are base tables I created. I didn't have your tables to work with so I had to create them. The view is persistent though. Here is an excellent article about tally tables. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/ The technique used for building the columns is known as a crosstab. I personally prefer it to a PIVOT. I find the syntax less obtuse and it has been proven to have a slight edge over pivot for performance. You can read more about it here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/63681/

Comment: Thanks for the links man, it will take me a while to get this figured out.I really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. I love the attitude that you want to learn it and understand instead of just blindly saying "it works, I will put in production". Feel free to ask for clarification on parts if you need it.